# Moving a shape in kineticJS towards mouse click

Tags: meteor, kineticjs

I am experimenting with Meteor and KineticJS.  What I'm trying to do is to create a shape, and move it towards a mouse click on the stage.  The position should be saved to the mongoDB so that all connected clients can be updated.

I haven't gotten far yet, but this is what I've got.  I basically need a way to do two things:

1. How can I make a shape move towards the mouse click on the stage
   and stop when it gets there?
2. Is there a better way of checking
       the current position of a shape, other than the gameLoop that I
       tried below?  It works, but it feels wrong.

Thank you!

```
//client.js code

var player = null;
var playerAnim = null;

Template.container.rendered = function () {

  var myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: myCanvas,
        width: 1024,
        height: 1024
      });

      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

      // add the layer to the stage
      stage.add(layer);

      // add click listener for the stage
      $(stage.getContent()).on('click', function(evt) {
        //stage was clicked

        //Find the player shape in the database
        Players.find().forEach(function (dbShape) {
        player = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon(dbShape);

        // setup an animation to move the player to the right
          playerAnim = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {

          var velocity = 50;
          var dist = velocity * (frame.timeDiff / 1000);
          player.move(dist, 0);
          Players.update(dbShape._id, {$set: {x: player.attrs.x, y: player.attrs.y}});
          }, layer);

          playerAnim.start();        
          layer.add(player);
          layer.draw();
        });
      });

    //make a gameLoop to check the position and stop the animation
    Meteor.setInterval(function(gameLoop){          
      if(player.attrs.x > 500){
        playerAnim.stop();
      }
    },  500);

    Meteor.autosubscribe(function () {
    // clear the canvas
    if (layer) {
      layer.removeChildren();
      layer.clear();
    }
    // populate the canvas with the Shapes collection
    Players.find().forEach(function (dbShape) {
      var player = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon(dbShape);

      layer.add(player);
      layer.draw();
    });
  });

}
```

Comment: If the target (mouseclick) position is changing quickly or it's position is critical to your game, then move the shape within the game loop.  If not, you might use a Tween to move the shape (Tweens are useful because they are fire-and-forget).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I would use a tween to do this. Grab your object, get mouse position, and on `mousedown` or `click` create a Tween for your node to that mouse position.

   ```
   layer.on('mousedown', function() {
       var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
       var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
       node: rect,
       duration: 1,
       x: mousePos.x,
       y: mousePos.y,
       opacity: 1,
       strokeWidth: 6,
       scaleX: 1.5
     }).play();

   });
   ```

   [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/azdcF/)

   **Note:** To make the `layer` **clickable**, we need to add a transparent rectangle with the size of the width and height of the stage to the layer. See in the jsfiddle the `Kinetic.Rect` I made named `var bg`
2. Would putting the check inside the animation work for you?

   ```
   playerAnim = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
      var velocity = 50;
      var dist = velocity * (frame.timeDiff / 1000);
      player.move(dist, 0);
      Players.update(dbShape._id, {$set: {x: player.attrs.x, y: player.attrs.y}});

      if(player.getX() > 500){
        this.stop();
      }
   }, layer);
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I had first considered using a Tween, but I hoped for a moveBy parameter where I can input a speed.  With the current Kinetic tween, only a duration is specified, so the speed of the tween changes depending on the distance.  I suppose this is easily fixed with some simple math, however.

Comment: Haha yeah unfortunately speed isn't a property for Tween. But, if you know the velocity you want to move at, and if you know the time or distance, then you can calculate the other: v = d/t (simple Physics! :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity)